# Categorical plotting with seaborn raises ValueError: object arrays are not supported

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Here is part of a Pandas DataFrame I am working with:

```
all_samples = pd.DataFrame({'Group': {0: 'One', 3: 'One', 4: 'One', 5: 'One', 7: 'One'},
 'Sample': {0: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 7: 2},
 'VAF': {0: 0.0009577524741938917,
  3: 0.0006907269901571404,
  4: 0.001246660730186999,
  5: 0.00128,
  7: 0.0012338062924120913}})
```

If I try to plot the data as a scatterplot everything works fine:

```
sns.catplot(x="Group", y="VAF", hue="Sample", dodge=True,
            palette="pastel", data=all_samples.head(20));
```

But when I try to plot the data as a violin, or boxplot like this:

```
sns.catplot(x="Group", y="VAF", hue="Sample", kind='violin',
            palette="pastel", data=all_samples.head(20));
```

I get a `ValueError: object arrays are not supported` error. Is my DataFrame structured poorly or something?

#### Update:

Since it worked for others I tried the example I posted and it works for me. Then when I use my full DataFrame; I converted it to a dictionary then to a DataFrame and now it worked just fine. `temp = pd.DataFrame(all_samples.to_dict())` and then plotting like this: `sns.violinplot(x='Group', y='VAF', hue='Sample', palette='pastel', data=temp)`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to post my original data now to understand what is going wrong. Does this makes sense to anybody?

Comment: I don't get an error I am using `sns.__version__ == '0.9.0'`

Comment: Concerning the debugging of the data, you may try different subsets of your data and see if this changes something. If it is only some rows of data causing the error, you might isolate a small enough subset to provide within the question.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on `seaborn` version 0.9, however, in my case, the graph is cropped off.

If you want to plot a violin plot, you can call the `violinplot` function directly:

```
sns.violinplot(x='Group', y='VAF', hue='Sample', palette='pastel', data=all_samples);
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just checked this error with an artificial dataset and realized that some forms of creating Panda's DataFrames using ints make the column type be an object and not an int, and this is probably causing problems with violin diagram in Seaborn.

Using Colab, the following example shows why one plot works and other not.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sbs
import random 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

column_names = ["x","y"]
random_set = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

# not the better way of creating a DF, but possible
for i in range(100):
  d_util = {"x" : random.choice(random_set),
            "y" : random.randint(1,100)}
  df = df.append(d_util, ignore_index = True)

# See the types...
print("Original Types: ",df.dtypes)

# Now the "magic"
fix = pd.DataFrame(df.to_dict()) #what? What was wrong with the DataFrame?
print("New Types: ",fix.dtypes)

# This works
sbs.violinplot(x='x', y='y', data=fix)

#this not
sbs.violinplot(x='x', y='y', data=df)
```

The output is:

```
Original Types:  x    object
y    object
dtype: object
New Types:  x    object
y     int64
dtype: object
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d8663aa8f635> in <module>()
     25 
     26 #this not
---> 27 sbs.violinplot(x='x', y='y', data=df)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py in _asarray_validated(a, check_finite, sparse_ok, objects_ok, mask_ok, as_inexact)
    247     if not objects_ok:
    248         if a.dtype is np.dtype('O'):
--> 249             raise ValueError('object arrays are not supported')
    250     if as_inexact:
    251         if not np.issubdtype(a.dtype, np.inexact):

ValueError: object arrays are not supported
```

[image: Figure when it works]

The next example, creating the Data Frames with correct types, also works.

```
# Another option when creating the dataframe 

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sbs
import random 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


random_set = ['A','B']

dfw = pd.DataFrame({'x' : pd.Series(dtype='str'),
                   'y' : pd.Series(dtype='int')})


for i in range(100):
  d_util = {"x" : random.choice(random_set),
            "y" : random.randint(1,100)}
  dfw = dfw.append(d_util, ignore_index = True)

print("Original Types: ",dfw.dtypes)

x = sbs.violinplot(x='x', y='y', data=dfw)
```

You can check it in https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uc_wr7zsjdfkX9cdFI943trVQR-_nWx0?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

So I just went through the same problem and in my case, it was the dataset having string values in the form of "TRUE" and "FALSE" which I thought were changed. Might be relevant for someone going through the same now.